# What is the word for “something discovered in the past that gets rediscovered and becomes relevant many years later”?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In history of science and engineering, certain discoveries or inventions are ignored and discarded until after somebody other than the original inventor rediscovers and popularizes them many years later.

Is there a phrase for such inventions?

Comment: I inquired with ChatGPT and I received a surprisingly good answer: "sleeping giant". 

Here's the elaboration that ChatGPT provided:
"This phrase describes an idea or invention that has been dormant or overlooked for a long period of time, but suddenly becomes relevant or valuable when a new development or change in the market occurs. It refers to the idea that the potential of the invention was always there but was not recognized or realized until the right conditions arose."

Answer (score 0):

**Phrases:**

- Breathed new life into
- Breathed fresh life into

**Single words:**

- Rekindled
- Resuscitated
- Revived
- Reintroduced
- Reacquainted
- Re-established

Though the phrases and words above are not perfect fit, they may serve your purpose.